# Postgres eliminates decimal precision when casting a large float where first number in decimal portion <= 1 to real dtype

Tags: sql, postgresql

If you cast a large enough number with decimal precision to **real** where the first number in the decimal portion is less than or equal to 1 then the decimal portion is eliminated.

```sql
-- decimal precision is captured

-- 3 x 10^5 + 0.1
select 300000.1::real

OUTPUT:
300000.1
```

```sql
-- decimal precision is not captured

-- 3 x 10^6 + 0.1
select 3000000.1::real

OUTPUT:
3000000
```

```sql
-- decimal precision is captured

-- 3 x 10^6 + 0.2
select 3000000.2::real

OUTPUT:
3000000.2
```

I checked Postgres documentation and see that **real** dtype is "variable-precision, inexact" with a range of "6 decimal digits precision". I am not sure why decimal precision is captured in the third example but not the second since the size of the number is the same, just a larger decimal portion. Can someone explain this please?

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: michotross which postgres documentation are you referring to and how it would impact your in case scenarios. Please elaborate on same

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 0):

That's just a coincidence.

`real` is stored in binary, so when you exceed the precision, it's the luck of the draw how far from the intended decimal number the value is.